# I'd like someone to break these sentences down so I can understand them better

Tags: grammar, syntax

> まず私が罹った膵臓の病気っていうのはちょっと前まで判明した時にはほとんどの人が死んじゃう病気の王様だった。

To start things off, pancreatic diseases like what I’ve been diagnosed with are the kings of sudden deaths.

From what I can understand, this is what this sentence means in english (without the part I don't understand). I'd like to know how 「ちょっと前まで判明した時には」fits into this sentence. I feel like the phrase is completely out of place. If には is added to the end, it sounds like everyone dies before it is diagnosed, but that obviously doesn't sound right.

> 人数の設定がクラス毎に自由で、結果僕一人だけが担当をしていた図書館委員になのりをあげた。

I don't understand the first half of the sentence. Does「人数の設定がクラス毎に自由で」mean every class gets to decide how many people are on duty for the library committee?

Comment: (1) Is it really 膵臓病気 without typo(s)? (2) I don't get much the meaning of the second sentence as a whole either. Most likely we need longer excerpt before this sentence.

Comment: 膵臓病気 -> typo for 膵臓**の**病気, or 膵臓病, and なのりあげた -> typo for なのり**を**あげた, no?

Comment: I saw an isolated case where [名乗り上げる itself is a verb](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E5%90%8D%E4%B9%97%E3%82%8A%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B) on Weblio but it does seem like it's very rare. I'm also curious about the source of this text.

Comment: I think I found the source, go to https://ameblo.jp/lily031/entry-12158244657.html and look for the entry ２０××年１１月２３日 slightly before halfway down the page. The committee stuff can be found a few paragraphs later.

Comment: @JansthcirlU Thanks, the 図書館委員 line is also on that page, with slightly different wording for some reason.

Comment: So at the end of the day, does「担当していた図書館委員会」mean *the committee of which the speaker is in charge*?

Comment: @JansthcirlU If we believe that article, yes. (It says 図書委員会, though)

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth That would be because I'm reading from the light novel published version I think. Also I made some typos that Chocolate kindly fixed for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would parse:

> まず、（私が罹った）膵臓**の**病気っていうのは、ちょっと前まで（判明した時にはほとんどの人が死んじゃう）病気の王様だった。

The basic structure is:

> 膵臓の病気っていうのは、ちょっと前まで病気の王様だった。
> "The pancreatic disease was the king of diseases until a while ago."

The relative clause 私が患った modifies 膵臓の病気.
The relative clause 判明した時にはほとんどの人が死んじゃう modifies 病気の王様.

So the whole sentence means:
"To start things off, the pancreatic disease (that I’ve been diagnosed with) was the king of diseases until a while ago (which killed most people in case they were identified)."

---

> （人数の設定がクラス毎に自由で、結果僕一人だけが担当をしていた）図書館委員になのり**を**あげた。

人数の設定がクラス毎に自由で、結果僕一人だけが担当をしていた is a relative clause that modifies 図書館委員.　The subject of 名乗りを上げた is not mentioned. Someone unmentioned did the action 図書館委員に名乗りを上げる.

"(Someone) stood as a candidate for the library committee member (for which every class can decide how many people are on duty, and as a result, I was the only one in charge).

Comment: Could it also be「担当をしていた図書館委員」as in "The library board in charge" and the speaker himself standing as a candidate?

Comment: ん？ The speaker was already 担当していた, so he was not a candidate.

Comment: この部分の関係がちょっとよく分からなくて文脈が必要だと思ったんですが、「担当をしていた」がどこにかかるか（そしてどういう意味か）によって節の構造も変わらざるをえないんじゃないかなあという気がします

Comment: thanks so much! You even fixed the typos I made. I was in a bit off a hurry when I wrote this. I understand the sentences much better now. Although I do think JansthcirlU might be right about 「担当をしていた図書館委員」meaning "the library board in charge". The source is 「君の膵臓が食べたい」for anyone curious

Comment: @shuuanson I haven't read the real book, but if the synopsis is unchanged from that blog, choco is right, and the subject is the girl.

Comment: @shuuanson actually I had already corrected my answer, the whole "in charge" part was just confusing because the surrounding context was not clear. The speaker is in charge of the library committee as indicated in the beginning of the webpage by「図書委員としての任務を忠実にこなしている最中に、山内桜良がおかしな告白をしてきた。」

Answer (score 2):

## First sentence

> 私が罹った①　膵臓の病気ていう②　の③　は④

③ "The kind of illness"「の」here is used as a noun placeholder (the illness)

① "that I suffer from,"

② "which affects my pancreas,"

④+⑩ "used to be" (past tense because of the「だった」at the end, see next part)

> ちょっと前まで⑤ 判明した時⑥ には⑦ ほとんどの人が死んじゃう⑧ 病気の王様⑨ だった⑩。

⑨ "the king of diseases that"

⑧ "most people would die from"

⑦ "when"

⑥ "they were identified,"

⑤ "until not too long ago."

The speaker goes on to explain that they hardly showed any symptoms even now when they've already been diagnosed.

## Second sentence

> 人数の設定がクラス毎に自由で①、

① "Because each class could freely choose their respective number of representatives,"

> 結果② 一人だけが③ 担当をしていた図書委員会④ の空席に⑤ 名乗りを上げた⑥。

③ "only one person"

⑥ "ended up announcing their candidacy"

⑤ "for the vacant positions"

④ "in the library committee of which I was in charge"

② "as a result."

### I decided to take [the source?](https://ameblo.jp/lily031/entry-12158244657.html) as a basis for my translation. Apparently this website offers a transcription of the book「君の膵臓を食べたい」("I want to eat your pancreas") by 住野よる (Yoru Sumino), which has also been adapted into a movie and an anime.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize the book was online too. I'm reading the novel from a paperback copy. This was really easy to understand as well.

Comment: No problem! Good luck and have fun reading your novel!